# Android ScrollView not adjusting to new EditText content

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` contained in a `ScrollView` contained in a `LinearLayout`.

```
public class ScrollingTextView extends LinearLayout {

  public ScrollingTextView(Context context) {

      super(context);

      scrollView = new ScrollView(context);
      scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
      scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

      editText = new EditText(context);
      editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
      editText.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

      scrollView.addView(editText);
      this.addView(scrollView);
    }
}
```

I also have this in my Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

The problem is, when I type new content in the `EditText`, the `ScrollView` size is not adjusted. When I try to scroll physically, the `ScrollView` does not allow me to scroll the extra content.

It seems that the `EditText` height becomes larger than the `ScrollView` height.

Any ideas as to how to force the `ScrollView` to match the `EditText` height?

Comment: What LayoutParams is being used in both cases? For editText is it ScrollView.LayoutParams?

Comment: @SlowAndSteady not sure what you mean. The code above is all the code I have for this functionality.

Comment: try scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)); and for editText try editText.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: @SlowAndSteady no luck. Same issue.

Comment: I've updated the code to show the full class definition, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: I just tried the exact code in my editor and it seems to work fine on Pixel. For testing I added ScrollingTextView in layout file with 60dp height. I enter some long text and am able to scroll within the edit text. How are you consuming ScrollingTextView?

Comment: It's a React Native module. If it doesn't work automatically, can you think of a way to do it manually? i.e observe text change and update scroll view size?

Comment: Surprisingly, setting `editText.setMovementMethod(null);` fixes the scrolling issue, however, hides the cursor. I'm getting close..